# python behaviour when passed an asterisk

Tags: python, input, parameter-passing

I'm writing a small script, that should be able to handle multiple files. So I've added that files can be passed comma seperated, and do a arg.split(',') and then handle each one.

Now I've wanted to add asterisk as input possibility like

```
python myPythonScript.py -i folder/*
```

If I print the the argument to option -i right when I access it the first time I get

```
folder/firstFileInFolder.txt
```

But if I call my script with

```
python myPythonScript.py -i someFolder/someFile,folder/*
```

it works just fine. Does anyone have an idea, why python might behave that way?

Comment: It's not python doing this - it's your shell ..

Comment: The standard approach to passing multiple files is to let your shell glob the inputs which will pass them as separate arguments.  Don't use comma separated.  If you're iterating over the contents of the passed files, the Python `fileinput` module may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this script

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

python script.py *

your shell expands the asterisk before python sees it.

Comment: @nneonneo you got me there :)

Comment: how do I get the whole list it expands to? right now I have this
`elif opt == '-i':
    all_documents = arg.split(',')`
Can I get the shell to expand the input that is after the comma?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your shell is expanding the asterisk for the non-comma separated case.  If you know that the user may specify an asterisk as part of a file name as in your second example, you can have Python do the path expansion by using the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#module-glob) module.

```
from glob import glob
glob('*')
```

code which would allow either the shell or Python to do asterisk expansion may look something like this:

```
import glob
file_list = []
for pattern in sys.argv[1:]:
    file_list.extend(glob.glob(pattern))
```

In your case, using a comma as a separator would then prevent you from using a comma as part of a filename.